# How to find out the albums contained in folders a photo is in

Tags: macos, applescript, photos, photos.app

I need to find in which album some photos are contained. I've already tried with a script the script below without success. As the albums are contained inside folders the script doesn't seem to be able to find the albums.

```
tell application "Photos"
    set selectedPhotos to get selection -- Get the selected photo
    try
        if selectedPhotos is {} then error -- No selection
    on error
        display alert "Select a photo, then run this script to find albums containing the photo."
        return
    end try
    -- Find albums that contain the photo's ID
    set selectedPhotoId to get id of first item in selectedPhotos
    set containingAlbums to get albums whose id of media items contains selectedPhotoId
    try
        if containingAlbums is {} then error
    on error
        display alert "That photo is not in any albums"
    end try
    -- Get names of albums and show them
    set albumNames to name of albums whose id of media items contains selectedPhotoId
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ", "
    albumNames as string
    display alert "Albums containing selected photo: " & (albumNames as string)
end tell
```

This is a sample structure

```
My Albums
 - Folder 1
 -- Album 1
 -- Album 2
 - Folder 2
 -- Folder 2A
 --- Album 3
 - Album 4
```

The script works fine when the photos are contained in Album 4. However, if the photos are inside any of Albums 1, 2 or 3, the script is unable to find them.

When the searched photo is in an album nested in a folder, the result of the script is following two alerts:

The first: `That photo is not in any albums`

The second: `Albums containing selected photo:`

One option would be to move all albums out of the folders, but it would be a pretty large job. I was wondering if the script could be changed to include the search within multiple levels of folders.

Comment: What do you mean when you say your script doesn't work. Explain. Specifics are useful, including the output you're getting and why it's not the output you want.

Comment: You're right, @CJK. I've created this question last night in too much haste - I've updated it now with further information.

Comment: Thanks, Martin. That makes everything a lot clearer. In fact, even without the script, your folder structure coupled with the first sentence immediately after it tells me exactly what you’re doing, and why it’s not giving satisfactory results. The pandemic is taking a lot of my time up, but I will see about drafting a script this week. In the meantime, compare the result from your script if you replace `albums whose...` with `albums in folders whose...`; and then `albums in folders in folders whose...`. Ever had to list the contents of a directory plus all subdirectories too ?